# Dagre replacement for directed graph layouts?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a directed graph layout engine. I just need the heady math for node/edge positioning as I want to do the rendering myself. [Dagrejs](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre) seems to be the best option, but the huge **[DEPRECATED]** warning on the repo has me worried. Is there an active alternative that will do the job?

Comment: I've exactly the same requirement. I'm looking for an alternative to calculate the positions of the nodes in a tree, but render them myself instead of getting any SVG or canvas object. I'm using absolutely positioned HTML elements that I want to arrange. Currently, I'm using `dagre` but I'm not happy with the result of calculated edges, they look a bit untidy.

Comment: 2023 bump - have you had any luck finding an alternative?

Comment: @TimDog No, still using dagre. I'll post here if I come across anything.

Comment: for the record, I ended up using [graphviz](https://github.com/hpcc-systems/hpcc-js-wasm) as a wasm module with [deno deploy](https://deno.com/deploy) and making an api call out w the dot language to calc the coordinates for my front end app...worked pretty well